# How can I delete a team I created?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have created a private team and invited some friends and colleagues to use it.

Now I want to delete this team and I can't find a way on how can I do that?

I've tried to look at other posts posted here but seems that there is no suggestion on how to delete an already existing team which I'm the only admin.

Comment: https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000191037-cancelling-your-teams-subscription

Comment: @Sam Is it just me or does the sentence in that cancellation screen shot for the basic tier where it says: "Additionally, your team members will no longer be able to log in to Stack Overflow" sound a little over dramatic :)

Comment: @JonClements probably an old screenshot and might have been fixed now

Comment: The button is now in the billing page, `https://stackoverflow.com/c/<yourteam>/admin/billing/plan`